# In AWS Cloud formation, How to specify two resources with Ref in IAM Policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

How to combine two same IAM Policies in one if they are target two different resources. One of the resource has Join and Ref. Can below two Policies be merged to single in CloudFormation Template?

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "s3:DeleteObject"
    - "s3:DeleteObjectTagging"
    - "s3:GetObjectAcl"
    - "s3:GetObjectTagging"
    - "s3:PutObject"
    - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    - "s3:PutObjectTagging"
  Resource:
    !Join
      - ''
      - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
        - !Ref TestBucketName
        - '/*'

- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "s3:DeleteObject"
    - "s3:DeleteObjectTagging"
    - "s3:GetObjectAcl"
    - "s3:GetObjectTagging"
    - "s3:PutObject"
    - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    - "s3:PutObjectTagging"
  Resource: "arn:aws:s3:::SecondTestBucket/Download/*"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use [!Sub or Fn::Sub](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) instead of `Join` as below for the clear code.

```yaml
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "s3:DeleteObject"
    - "s3:DeleteObjectAcl"
    - "s3:DeleteObjectTagging"
    - "s3:GetObjectAcl"
    - "s3:GetObjectTagging"
    - "s3:PutObject"
    - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    - "s3:PutObjectTagging"
  Resource:
    - !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${TestBucketName}/*
    - "arn:aws:s3:::SecondTestBucket/Download/*"
```

Comment: Can the ` Sub ` work for input parameters? ` TestBucketName ` is input parameter to Cloud formation template in this case.

Comment: Yes, it works for `Parameters`

You can refer [here](https://github.com/citrix/citrix-adc-aws-cloudformation/blob/2ee388d215e275ac34d6c0291fdb0e30c38d3bc5/templates/standalone/3nic/standalone-3nic-adc.yaml#L381)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `!Join` or `!GetAtt` to reference your created resources.

Note: `!GetAtt` only can be used if the resources you created can return Arn

```
  ExampleS3AccessPolicy:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy'
    Properties:
      Description: example-s3-access-Policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 's3:DeleteObject'
              - 's3:GetObject'
              - 's3:ListBucket'
              - 's3:PutObject'
              - 's3:ListMultipartUploadParts'
              - 's3:AbortMultipartUpload'
            Resource:
              - !Join ['',['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref ExamplePublishedS3, '/*']]
              - !Join ['',['arn:aws:s3:::', !Ref ExamplePrivateS3, '/*']]
              - !GetAtt ExamplePublishedS3.Arn
              - !GetAtt ExamplePublishedS3.Arn
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
- Effect: Allow
  Action:
    - "s3:DeleteObject"
    - "s3:DeleteObjectAcl"
    - "s3:DeleteObjectTagging"
    - "s3:GetObjectAcl"
    - "s3:GetObjectTagging"
    - "s3:PutObject"
    - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
    - "s3:PutObjectTagging"
  Resource:
    - !Join
      - ''
      - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
        - !Ref TestBucketName
        - '/*'
    - "arn:aws:s3:::SecondTestBucket/Download/*"
```